# How to show front end through back end

Tags: php, html

Question might be stupid however, I am curious how can I for example, after user makes an account, redirect them to the home page and display success message, however I don't want to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` since people can type paramaters in URL and get the success message.

Comment: "since people can type paramaters in URL and get the success"...and why would that be a problem? All they'd do is display a "success" message to themselves, it wouldn't mean they'd actually _done_ anything useful.

Comment: Its not a problem, just would like to remove that and let users not be able to do that

Comment: I'd suggest using Session is one way to go then (just remember to clear the session variable after the mesage has been displayed). Or, have the current script (the one which creates the account) echo the "success" message itself, and then only after a few seconds delay you can redirect the user to the home page.

Comment: Or you could do everything via AJAX, so there's no redirecting at all. But that might require a bigger redesign of your site.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to store the value in `$_SESSION` https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

This will not be editable via the end user. After log in, you could have something like:

```php
<?php 
  if(isset($_SESSION['success_message'])){
    echo $_SESSION['success_message'];
  }
?>
```